# Maven Multi-Module Project

Tags: java, maven, maven-reactor

I'm trying to perform a Maven build in a multi-module project structured like the below:

```
-> Project-Parent
    -> Project-Utils
        - pom.xml
    -> Project-Service
        - pom.xml
    - pom.xml
```

Given what I've read on advanced Reactor options, I could possibly use the following command to build the `Project-Utils` project alone:

```
mvn -pl ./Project-Utils clean install
```

However, it seems that I would have to define `Project-Utils` in my parent POM as such:

```
<modules>
    <module>Project-Utils</module>
</modules>
```

Is there any way I can use the `--project` option without having to define modules in the parent POM?

Comment: Can you try `mvn -pl 'Project-Utils' clean install` to check if that works for you from the parent directory.

Comment: @nullpointer Unfortunately not: `Could not find the selected project in the reactor: Project-Utils -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `modules`?

Comment: @DanW Well, the project ultimately would have hundreds of modules, and I am looking to see if the parent POM could be better structured or maintained by not having to maintain module definitions in it.

Answer (score -1):

In the module POM make sure you set relativePath

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

This wil make sure maven will search for the parent pom in your repositiory.

To install the parent into the repository, navigate to the parent directory and execute

```
mvn clean install
```

and then navigate to the directory of the module and execute

```
mvn clean package
```

it should pick up the installed parent